# TypeInitializationException using OpenSsl.net

Tags: c#, c++, openssl

I'm trying to use OpenSsl.net but I'm getting a TypeInitializationException which is confounding me.
The set up is:

- I have a console application which has a project reference to openssl.net (In fact I'm using the fork from here : https://github.com/marcominetti/openssl-net)
- I have compiled openssl (for 32 bit windows) on my machine and copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to the bin/Debug folder of my console application.
- The bin/Debug folder also contains libcrypto.so
- My machine is 64 bit (the 64 bit build of openssl fails but that's another issue)
- The console application is set to platform target of x86

However, at runtime I get a TypeInitializationException with detail:

Unable to load DLL 'librypto': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

After looking more closely at the code in the fork it looks as if it is setup more for a linux environment than windows (which is the OS I'm using - probably should have mentioned that...)

In the Native.cs it specifies DLLNAME as libcrypto rather than libeay32. It appears this may be for linux systems rather than windows.

The app.config for the managed open ssl does include some dllmap sections which appear to attempt to redirect requests for libcrypto to libeay32.dll but this doesn't seem to work (I don't know if this is for mono only?).

I've set the DLLNAME to libeay32 and everything appears to work as expected.